# Algorand ASA - What happens if a wallet hasn't added an ASA prior to transfer?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, algorand

What happens if a wallet hasn't added an ASA prior to transfer? Does the transaction fail? If an asset is frozen,  I assume the manager address can still move the asset between other wallets?  But, an asset being frozen stops wallet to wallet transfers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if a wallet hasn't added an ASA prior to the transfer the transaction will fail.

As for the frozen question, this is from the docs:

> An Asset Freeze Transaction is issued by the Freeze Address and results in the asset receiver address losing or being granted the ability to send or receive the frozen asset.

A freeze is just flipping a switch about what the holder can do with the asset. However, a clawback:

> The clawback address represents an account that is allowed to transfer assets from and to any asset holder (assuming they have opted-in).

So in this scenario, a clawback would take precedence and the sender could still move an asset even if frozen.